# SSRS report only works with a specific user and for the other users, it stucks in loading forever

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have some reports deployed by SSRS 2016. They were working perfectly until yesterday. Now There is only one user can use them and the other can just see the reports name. If the other users try to run the reports it is going to stuck in loading stage and nothing more happens. I took a look at SQL Server profiler, the only time that report sends the query to the database is when that specific user runs the reports.

All the users are in the same domain.

Let me know if you need more info. Thanks.

Comment: did you create any linked report ?

Comment: How are the reports being used? report manager?  what does stuck in loading stage mean?  What is actually happening?  Does that user have different access rights (report manager folder permissions, or your database tables that the reports hit) from the other users that cannot use the reports?

Comment: @LONG I did not.

Comment: @ivan7707 The reports are created by sql server data tool and all connected to DB by sa user. When the others run the report they can see just "loading.... " and nothing happens even an error.

Comment: @RamtinNekavand, it is blank page or showing any other message, what do you mean the `loading stage`, what they saw is the green circle keeps spinning or just blank page?

Comment: @LONG Cycle with "Loading...."

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed by changing Service Account setting (from *Network Service* to *domain user*) in Reporting Services Configuration Manager.